# modprobe fuse returns module fuse not found

Tags: sshfs, fuse

I have ubuntu 12.04 and the kernel version is 2.6.32

```
 Linux user1 2.6.32-042stab083.2 #1 SMP Fri Nov 8 18:08:40 MSK 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When i run the command modprobe fuse it says

```
FATAL: Module fuse not found.
```

I have run apt-get remove libfuse2 and again installed fuse, libfuse and fuse-utils

But still i get the error Module fuse not found.

Regards

Answer (score 5):

First you can try to install module from cache,

> apt-cache search fuse

if this doesn't work--- you can install fuse module with module-assistant,

> apt-get install module-assistant
>
> apt-get install fuse-source
>
> cd /usr/src
>
> m-a prepare
>
> m-a a-i fuse
>
> depmod -ae $(uname -r)

Now you can,

**modprobe fuse**