# Cannot mount windows ntfs drive on Ubuntu. Error Fuse not found

Tags: mount, ntfs, modprobe, fuse

I recently updated the kernel to 4.10.3 and since then I have not been able to mount windows ntfs drives. It was working perfectly fine in my old kernel 4.4.0-64.

I have disabled fast-boot on Windows. ntfs-3g is installed.

The error I'm getting is [image: modprobe fuse error.]

I tried adding

```
    abhijitnathwani@abhijitnathwani:/usr/src$ modprobe fuse
    modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not found in directory /lib/modules/4.10.3
```

How do i explicitly install the fuse module. I followed the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450570/modprobe-fuse-returns-module-fuse-not-found), but it did not do any good to me.